# custom template wasn't recognized in magento layout

Tags: php, xml, magento

I created a simple page that display a custom front end page. I have cleared my cache and checked all my typo errors how ever I can't figure out why my template was not rendering. I'm using magento version 1.9.1.0.

This is my config file saved in app/code/local/Rts/Prodselector/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <prodselector>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Rts_Prodselector</module>
                    <frontName>productselector</frontName>
                </args>
            </prodselector>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <prodselector module="productselector_index_result">
                    <file>prodselector/result.xml</file>
                </prodselector>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

This is my controller saved in app/code/local/controllers/IndexController.php

```
class Rts_Prodselector_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function resultAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

this is my layout xml saved in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/prodselector/result.xml

```
<layout>
    <productselector_index_result>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="productselector_index_result" template="prodselector/result.phtml" ></block>
        </reference>
    </productselector_index_result>
</layout>
```

and my template was saved in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/prodselector/result.phtml that contains pure html.

Did I missed something? I am new to magento and I'm stuck with this simple problem.

====UPDATE===

The page renders three column layout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout file,  use

```
<prodselector_index_result>
```

instead of

```
<productselector_index_result>
```

since you've defined it that way in your config.xml